# Play MIDI file from Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, midi

Is it possible to play a MIDI file (existing on the hard drive) from Common Lisp?  If so, how?

Comment: It seems to me that you have to read the MIDI file using http://www.cliki.net/MIDI%20Library and then choose your ad-hoc audio library (http://www.cliki.net/Music) to reproduce it from the interpreted data.

Comment: @Vinko Vrsalovic:  That seems to be an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Common Lisp implementation supports [FFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface), you might be able to use a library like [PortAudio](http://www.portaudio.com/). (Also see the [Common Lisp Foreign Function Interface](http://common-lisp.net/project/cffi/) project). Another option is to use the venerable [Simple DirectMedia Layer](http://www.libsdl.org/) which already have Lisp bindings. (But you may also have to get [Timidity](http://timidity.sourceforge.net/)).